# Firebase writing app success but failed to see in console

Tags: android, json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, crud

I followed this [tutorial](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/#Adding-Firebase-Database) on how to write data on firebase using android.

I am able to get the message in form of toast, that says I successfully added data to firebase, but when I go to the firebase console, there is no data in my database.

What have I done so far to find the issue:

*I checked the google-services.json, the firebase URL is the same as my console.

*I debugged the data I inserted and it's not null.

*Virtual device has internet connection.

Comment: Please add your own code.

Comment: code is same as the tutorial

Comment: So you as ask us to debug the tutorial?